# How to know if I'm running a python script from eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I have a python script which is sometimes invoked from command line and sometimes from eclipse (during SW build).

Is there a way to know from within the python script if it is invoked from eclipse (without sending the script command line arguments)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Eclipse anymore since PyCharm is much more efficient for Python programming, but here are some ideas you can try:

⬥ You may have (or you can set) an environment variable when the script is launched with Eclipse.

For instance, with PyCharm, we have:

```
import os

print("PYCHARM_HOSTED: {!r}".format(os.environ['PYCHARM_HOSTED']))
# -> PYCHARM_HOSTED: '1'
```

You can have a similar environment variable with Eclipse. Check the `os.environ` dictionary.

⬥ You can have a different virtualenv, check the `sys.executable` value:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
# -> /Users/laurentlaporte/virtualenv/my_app/bin/python
```

⬥ When Eclipse launch your Python application, it creates a child process. In your Python application, you can search the parent process. It is a little complex, so…

To do that, you need to use [PsUtil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my use case is different.

I build a C/C++ application in two flavors - from command line and from eclipse. build system calls some python scripts. I wish that the stdout output of the python script will be different, depending on the invoking platform. that's why I need to know if script is running from eclipse...

Any idea? 

Thanks